# Firebird Default Collation

Tags: sql, firebird, anydac

When creating a Firebird database with the SQL below, it doesn't follow the default collation specified. But if I then alter the default collation after the database is created it works.

This creates a database that has a default collation of UTF8. I've tried leaving out the parameter for CharacterSet but that will create a database with not character set instead of the character set provided by the sql statement.

edit: Adding component setup

```
fConnection.Params.Add(Format('DriverID=%s',          ['IB']));
fConnection.Params.Add(Format('Database=%s',          [vDBFile]));
fConnection.Params.Add(Format('CharacterSet=%s',      ['UTF8']));
fConnection.Params.Add(Format('user_name=%s',         ['sysdba']));
fConnection.Params.Add(Format('password=%s',          ['masterkey']));
fConnection.Params.Add(Format('ExtendedMetadata=%s',  ['True']));
fConnection.Params.Add(Format('CreateDatabase=%s',    ['Yes']));
fConnection.Params.Add(Format('Protocol=%s',          ['TCPIP']));
fConnection.Params.Add(Format('Server=%s',            [pInfo.xServer]));

vScript := TADScript.Create(nil);
vScript.Connection := fConnection;
vScript.Transaction := fTransaction;

vScript.SQLScripts.Add.SQL.Text := 
    {leaving out quotes for readability}
    SET SQL DIALECT 3;
    SET CLIENTLIB 'c:\Firebird\fbclient.dll';
    CREATE DATABASE 'TEST'
      USER 'sysdba' PASSWORD 'masterkey'
      PAGE_SIZE 16384
      DEFAULT CHARACTER SET UTF8 COLLATION UNICODE_CI_AI;

vScript.ValidateAll;
vScript.ExecuteAll;
```

Executing the following SQL after the database is created will change the default collation to UNICODE_CI_AI

```
ALTER CHARACTER SET UTF8 SET DEFAULT COLLATION UNICODE_CI_AI
```

What SQL should I be using so that the default collation is set properly on database create?

I'm currently using Firebird 2.5.5 and accessing it from Delphi 2006 with the AnyDac components.

Comment: This doesn't seem related to Delphi. Isn't it about Firebird.

Comment: That's true. I was just adding as many parameters as I could think of to be totally clear. I'll remove the delphi tag.

Comment: I have tried this with 2.5.5 and 2.5.6 using ISQL, and I can't reproduce it. Exactly how do you execute the create database statement?

Comment: I've added how I execute the sql.

Comment: Mark, I'm gonna add the anydac tag back since it looks like it could be related.

Comment: I don't know anydac, but if I'd guess, the connection itself is creating the database (see your use of `CreateDatabase=True`), not your script.

Comment: I'm guessing the same thing. This is how I learned to create a new DB using the anydac components. Hoping someone can show me another (the right) way.